# Whats the fastest way to a draw grid of color on IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im trying to continually update a grid of colors on my iPhone screen ( testing with 50x50, but would like to scale up later ) I have done some research but can't seem to find an agreed upon solution. I've tested CAShapes and UIBezier paths and colored UIViews, but everything is slow. Is there another option besides diving into OpenGL or Metal? Doesn't need to be crazy fast, just faster than the before-mentioned options. Thanks, I'm working in Objective-C

Comment: What does “continually update a grid of colours” mean? Can you be more specific about what you are trying to do? How often are you updating? What does the grid look like? What was your code that was too slow? Etc...

Comment: I made a simple low res 3d renderer,  my "color-grid" is basically a simulated screen within my iPhone screen, because I dont know how to just color the actual pixels directly, id like the grid to be able to draw fast enough to update several times per second

Comment: it sounds like you need something much lower lvl than UIView or CALayer. You really do need to go into Metal for this sort of thing. Unless you can explain a bit more about what you want. It sounds like Metal is your best bet.

Comment: I can explain a bit more. Metal would be good in the long run. But I find it very confusing, and was trying to use my makeshift-renderer while I work out the kinks and than upgrade a better rendering method later. I just needed something a little more efficient than what I have for now. And I was hoping there was an answer within the basic tools, something more light weight than drawing 2500 UIViews or 2500 CAShapes

Comment: My Game Of Life app was able to draw something like 5,000 “pixels” per frame. Each was about 10x10 screen pixels. I did that by rendering a bitmap from a byte array. You could possibly do the same. Convert your data to a byte array where each byte represents the pixel colour. Then render it into a bitmap UIImage and then stick it in a UIImageView. You’d have to look up the individual steps as it’s been about 7 years since I wrote that.

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I need, I had read about that but assumed it was a slower process, now I know, thanks for the help

Comment: it might be quicker to draw the CIImage into a view rather than converting into UIImage and putting in a image view. But still give that a try.

Comment: Also... when drawing the pixels bigger. If you want them to be square there is a mode something like “nearestNeighbor” draw mode or something. It will make the pixels into squares when enlarged. Instead of blurring them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don’t want to dive into Metal then what I found much quicker for an app I wrote years ago was to put my data into a byte array and then use that array to render a bitmap image.

I don’t have all the details now. It used something like an “image provider” and various other parts. But it was much quicker than any other method I tried.

I was able to draw over 5000 “pixels” per frame using it so it should be good For you now.

Then you can either draw it into a view in `drawRect` or put it into a UIImageView.